# Cannot add module in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, lucene

I want to add lucene library to my project and **modify it's core methods**. I already have used lucene .jar files and that was the time when I didn't need modifying lucene core codes. But then I figure out that .jar files are pre-compiled files and we couldn't modify them at all.

Actually I googled almost every related page to find the solution (for many hours), but it seems that there is no helpful link on web!

[This is the link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206821415-How-to-modify-source-code-for-external-libraries) I found apparently useful. So I get the lucene 6.3.0 from [github](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/releases/tag/releases%2Flucene-solr%2F6.3.0) and followed the steps suggested by the writer.

After all nothing helped me in this way and I got plenty of errors in IntellijIdea! This is the first error:

> Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for
>   module 'Balog2'

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the settings of your project / libraries and its dependencies?

Comment: @Rao thank you for ur response. I've already added the lucene to dependencies (in addition to source) But I've got the same error ...

Comment: @Rao What do you mean by setting of project dependencies? Do you mean this path? `File -> Project structure -> Module -> dependencies` ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for dependency management? Your submodule *likely* does not have groovy as a dependency and therefore cannot locate the groovy compiler

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all

go here, pick a version of groovy that jives with the the java runtime you're using and add it to whatever dependency management solution you're using